# Using binding inside Xamarin XAML Extension

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding

I'm trying to bind EmbeddedImages to a ListView so I can show a different icon depending on the item of the list. Using [Working with Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images) tutorial I've managed to make a extension to show the embedded images, but only if i hard code the location to the icon.

So this works:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource (namespace).icon.png}"/>
```

but I can't bind to the icon I want. I've tried all these and none worked:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource {Binding _iconLocation}}" />

<Image Source="{Binding Source=local:ImageResource, Path=_iconLocation}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use binding you don't need to use markup extension. Extension is done *"Because there is no built-in type converter from string to ResourceImageSource"*.
In your model define

```
public ImageSource MyImageSource
        {
            get
            { //here you decide what resource to use
                return ImageSource.FromResource("(namespace).icon.png"); 
            }
        }
```

Then in xaml use

```
 <Image Source="{Binding MyImageSource}" />
```

And you don't need any extension classes

Comment: Sorry to downvote! Not trying to be mean: this is a sensible solution but it won't work, according to Microsoft's own documentation. It will only work if you're using compiler directives to customize the resource path on a per-platform basis. That is however the opposite of cross-platform coding. The actual question asked by OP, if it could be answered, would be the only way to dynamically set an image in a true cross-platform way. You need a markup extension, and you need some way to dynamically specify the string used after `local:ImageResource`.